# Calling a PHP file function in HTML with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have a question regarding one of our project which is developed by another developer proficient in angular js and I am not. So the issue is outlined below:
We have a report that is run daily using cron and it is in PHP and called directly, Now sometimes the server-side database fess up and we have to run this report manually.

I have an HTML file that can be used to make button but I can't use PHP functions directly in it. All the other HTML created in this project are using angular js controllers. I just want to know if there is a way of getting the PHP function to run in HTML. I can read through angularjs but there are all post data and i don't see a way of getting the get function. I read a lot online but i am not getting anywhere.

I will be really grateful if somebody points me in the right direction.

**I am looking for correct syntax of angularJS successful callback and then calling it in HTML**

PS: Please let me know if I am asking a redundant question rather than just giving me a negative reputation.

Example of it :

**PHP: public_html/XXXX/XXXX/php/cronHourly.php**

```
function sendMyEmail($receiverName,$receiverEmail,$mySubject,$myMessage,$senderName,$senderEmail){
    //global $company,$companyPhone,$defaultEmail,$domain,$shopAddress,$stationeryPrefix,$siteStatus,$reportArray,$Host,$Port,$Username,$Password,$serverRoot;
$stationeryHeader = "<body bgcolor='#cccccc' leftmargin='0' topmargin='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0'><style>
body {
      font-family: Arial;
       font-size: 12pt;
}
</style>
<br>
<table id='Table_01' border='0' cellpadding='0' align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' width='800'>

<tr><td width='20'></td><td><br>";

$stationeryFooter = "</td><td width='20'></td></tr>

</table></body>";

    //$mail = new PHPMailer();
     $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();  // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
    //$mail->SMTPSecure  = "ssl"; //Secure conection
    $mail->Host = 'xxxx.com';
    $mail->Port = 00;
    $mail->Username = 'postmaster@xxx.xom';  // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = ''; // SMTP password
    $mail->From = 'postmaster@xxx.com';
    $mail->FromName = $senderName;
    $mail->AddReplyTo($senderEmail, $senderName); 
    $mail->AddAddress($receiverEmail, $receiverName);//send a copy to the client
    $mail->Subject = $mySubject;
    $mail->WordWrap = 80;
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('x.png', 'csvimg', 'csv.png'); // attach file logo.jpg, and later link to it using identfier logoimg
    //$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($serverRoot.'/images/'.$stationeryPrefix.'Header.jpg', $stationeryPrefix.'Header', $stationeryPrefix.'Header.jpg');
    //$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($serverRoot.'/images/'.$stationeryPrefix.'Footer.jpg', $stationeryPrefix.'Footer', $stationeryPrefix.'Footer.jpg');
    //$headerImage = $serverRoot.'/images/'.$stationeryPrefix.'Header.jpg';
    $mail->Body = $stationeryHeader;
    $mail->Body .= $myMessage;
    $mail->Body .= $stationeryFooter;
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo '<br />Message FAILED to '.$receiverEmail;
        '.$reportArray[1],$company,$defaultEmail);
    }else{
        echo '<br />Message successfully sent to '.$receiverEmail;
    }//end if mail>send
}//end function sendMyEmail


?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mainpage">
<div>
<div class="row" style="padding:10px">

    <p> Click on this button Reports:</p>
   <button  ng-click=????" 
                        class="btn btn-default">Send Report</button>
</div>      

</div>
</div>
```

**POSSIBLE AngularJS:**

```
$scope.getreportrta = function (key) {
    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/XXXX/XXXX/php/cronHourly.php',
    };
    $http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.(*don't know how to fetch this*);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
}
```

Comment: you will get error from php side , you can see quotes mistakes.

Comment: First of all, I don't know how to call this PHP function in angular js, I don't know if that syntax is correct or not?

Comment: you dont need `public_html/XXXX/XXXX/php/cronHourly.php` to call php, in your server you are using apache and you have pointed ip or domain to particular folder where you place code, so first make sure and  find url from where php function work which u created.

Comment: For debugging purposes, put a `console.log(response)` in both the successCallback and errorCallback. Check the network tab of the Developer Console to see the response from the XHR.

Comment: I am thankful for your comments but what I want to know is how to get function in successful callback which can, in turn, be called in HTML, I am not sure of syntax so I can't further the cause before making those corrections.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found the answer to my question and i am posting it here if somebody comes across and needs help in the future:

**angular-script.js**

```
$scope.sendemail = function(info){
            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'ReportManual/manualemail.php',
            };
            //Call the URL and handle succes or error callback  --> G.H.
            $http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {
                     alert('The Report has been sent.');
                    console.log(response);

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert('Report has not been sent');
                 console.log(response);
            });

        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row" style="padding:10px">
  <p> Click on this button to send the Reports:</p>
   <button ng-click="sendemail()">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

**PHP:manualemail.php**

```
function sendMyEmail($receiverName,$receiverEmail,$mySubject,$myMessage,$senderName,$senderEmail){
    //global $company,$companyPhone,$defaultEmail,$domain,$shopAddress,$stationeryPrefix,$siteStatus,$reportArray,$Host,$Port,$Username,$Password,$serverRoot;
$stationeryHeader = "<body bgcolor='#cccccc' leftmargin='0' topmargin='0' marginwidth='0' marginheight='0'><style>
body {
      font-family: Arial;
       font-size: 12pt;
}
</style>
<br>
<table id='Table_01' border='0' cellpadding='0' align='center' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' width='800'>

<tr><td width='20'></td><td><br>";

$stationeryFooter = "</td><td width='20'></td></tr>

</table></body>";

    //$mail = new PHPMailer();
     $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->isSMTP();  // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; 
    //$mail->SMTPSecure  = "ssl"; //Secure conection
    $mail->Host = 'xxxx.com';
    $mail->Port = 00;
    $mail->Username = 'postmaster@xxx.xom';  // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = ''; // SMTP password
    $mail->From = 'postmaster@xxx.com';
    $mail->FromName = $senderName;
    $mail->AddReplyTo($senderEmail, $senderName); 
    $mail->AddAddress($receiverEmail, $receiverName);//send a copy to the client
    $mail->Subject = $mySubject;
    $mail->WordWrap = 80;
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('x.png', 'csvimg', 'csv.png'); // attach file logo.jpg, and later link to it using identfier logoimg
    //$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($serverRoot.'/images/'.$stationeryPrefix.'Header.jpg', $stationeryPrefix.'Header', $stationeryPrefix.'Header.jpg');
    //$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($serverRoot.'/images/'.$stationeryPrefix.'Footer.jpg', $stationeryPrefix.'Footer', $stationeryPrefix.'Footer.jpg');
    //$headerImage = $serverRoot.'/images/'.$stationeryPrefix.'Header.jpg';
    $mail->Body = $stationeryHeader;
    $mail->Body .= $myMessage;
    $mail->Body .= $stationeryFooter;
    if(!$mail->Send()){
        echo '<br />Message FAILED to '.$receiverEmail;
        '.$reportArray[1],$company,$defaultEmail);
    }else{
        echo '<br />Message successfully sent to '.$receiverEmail;
    }//end if mail>send
}//end function sendMyEmail


?>
```